# Creating a new cookie (overwriting the old one) keeps a list of old values?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Edit: Sorry! I forgot to include details. I'm using C# within a MVC4 project.

so I have some code here that is supposed to
 1. Create a new cookie if the UserID parameter is set and one hasn't been set already
 2. if a cookie has not been set and no UserID parameter is specified, set the UserID to 1
 3. if a new UserID parameter is there then update the cookie with the new UserID.

Problem is that ,If UserID is first set to Jake, then to Joe, then to Bob, I get a Cookie Value that looks like this "Bob, Joe, Jake". Is this normal? It seems like it'd be best to clear this list. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
public static void StoreID()
{
    if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserID"] == null) && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"] != null))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserID"].Value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }
    else if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserID"] == null) && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"] == null))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserID"].Value = "1";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }
    else if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserID"] != null) && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"] == null))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserID"].Value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so introducing subkeys fixed the problem. Not sure why this works the way it does - if someone has any input on why that'd be great! Here's the working code:

```
if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"]== null) && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"] != null))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["UserID"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"];
}
else if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"] == null) && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"] == null))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["UserID"] = "1";
}
else if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"] != null) && (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"] == null))
{

}
else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["UserID"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["UserID"];
}
```